# javascript async not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asynchronous

Logging rides alerts, logging users doesn't.

I can't figure out what's going on here...   There's no network errors.  Both data/users.json and data/rides.json are reaching the client fine.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "data/users.json",
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  success: function(data){
    users = data.users
    alert('Logging Uers');
}});

$.ajax({
  url: "data/rides.json",
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  success: function(data){
        alert('Logging rides');
    rides = data.rides
}});
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon, although javascript probably wouldn't care.

Comment: are u getting java script errors? How are these called on the page? and by "reaching the client" you mean "server" correct?

Comment: Implement the "error" callback and see if there is a result?

Comment: What happens if you `alert('Logging Uers')` before you access the `users` property of `data`, just as like as in the rides-success-function?

Comment: If the data sent from the server is not a valid JSON, you might not get a valid return, so, implement the error callback as @madflow said

Comment: have you looked in the console for any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `users = data.users` it's throwing an exception (caused by a possibly undefined `data`). Did you tried to comment that line?

Also, you should implement an error callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "data/users.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        //users = data.users;
        alert('Logging Users');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("ERROR");
        console.log(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone had invalidated the json file.  I fixed the syntax errors and it's working now.

Answer (score -2):

You may be getting a syntax error in both functions because of the lack of a semicolor after the assignment.  However, in your rides function, the assignment is after the alert, allowing the alert to fire.  In users, it is not.  Hence no alert.

Comment: I've fixed both of those and it's still not getting into that users success function